# Returning all manyToMany Polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a case where I have the following models:

Presentation, Slideshow, Video (not yet implemented)

These are all joined via a polymorphic many to many relationship, and everything looks fine. However I find the need to query for all "presentables" (both Slideshows and Videos) for a particular presentation, as I want to display them all in one place in a list.

How can I define this relationship, or am I doomed to create a function in my model to handle all of this?

Below is the models and DB schema:

**Presentation Model**

```
class Presentation extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function slideshows()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Slideshow', 'presentable'); //, 'presentables', 'presentable_id', 'presentable_type');
    }

    public function presentables()
    {
        //code in here to return all presentable objects
    }
}
```

**Slideshow Model**

```
<?php
class Slideshow extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    public function presentation()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Presentation', 'presentable', 'presentables', 'presentable_id', 'presentable_type');
    }
}
```

**presentables table**

```
Schema::create('presentables', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('presentation_id');
        $table->integer('order');
        $table->integer('presentable_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('presentable_type')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```